# How do I effectively backup my 3DS saved games?

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I lost a 3DS last year, and last week my SD card decided to turn half of itself into bad sectors.

I finally got around to using the built-in Data Management option and have a backup on my PC, but I read that the backup only works on this physical system.

How do I perform a real backup of my saved games?  My New 3DS XL is stock and unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on [Nintendo's support website](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70/~/how-to-back-up-save-data) where they say that you need system menu version 6.0.0-0U or higher to backup your save-data. You can follow the instructions [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70/~/how-to-back-up-save-data). Once the data is backed up, you can use the SD card to move the backup data to a PC or something.

Comment: I mentioned that already.  I have already done that as per my second paragraph, but this backup is system specific.  If I break/lose my current system, the backup doesn't work on another.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to backup saved games on a 3DS without modding one. I know a negative answer is not that helpful, but it is what it is.

If you have access to a second 3DS, you can do a system transfer from your device to that one (this [should include](https://www.ign.com/wikis/nintendo-3ds/3DS_to_New_3DS_or_3DS_XL_System_Transfer) your saved games), make a backup of the SD card of that second system, then transfer back. In case your 3DS breaks down, it should be possible to redo the transfer by [contacting Nintendo customer support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/74268/~/transferring-games-from-a-broken-3ds), then restore your games from the backup on that second system. Considering that you're limited to 1 system transfer per week, and the fact that you need a second device (which will be wiped) to do it, I doubt this is a useful approach unless you own two devices.